# How to execute JavaScript code from the AddressField bar?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I tried to make a JavaScript code and run it from the Address field bar but nothing happen. Can you help me guys with that?
Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
var number = document.getElementById('MT_CASE_EXTRA_MT_CAT_SEQ_NUM');
selectItemByValue(number, 24);
</script>
```

I have a webpage with DropDown list with options, i want to run script from the address bar to set the values in those DropDown lists and then add this script to the bookmark bar and make my life easier.

How i convert that code to JavaScript bookmarklet?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am assumming that selectItemByValue is defined already, maybe somewhere in the js script already loaded on the page.

Then for bookmarklet, use 
`javascript:var number = document.getElementById('MT_CASE_EXTRA_MT_CAT_SEQ_NUM');selectItemByValue(number, 24);`

(Ignore the line wrap. It's a single line.)

Comment: Do you have selectItemByValue defined properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it from location / URL bar:
Well, many browsers NOW have disabled it, because of some users, who fell for the trap posts on some social networking site posts like, "Copy paste this code in location bar & some magic will happen".

To get around with this, (at least on firefox,) You can use "tools->Web developer->web console (ctrl+shift+k)" to run that script.

Also, there is no about:config entry for override.

Similarly, there may be similar solution for other browsers.

Comment: Thank you for answer but still doesn't work, it says:ReferenceError: selectItemByValue is not defined

Comment: hmm... thought so. selectItemByValue function is not defined. You need to define it yourself, or use some alternate function.